# Get the result only FALSE when the answer is TRUE and FALSE

Tags: r

```
unique(k[[2]]-k[[1]]== c(1,1))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

What should I do if I want to get the result as FALSE(only FALSE) when the answer is TRUE and FALSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
length(unique(k[[2]]-k[[1]]==c(1,1)))==1
```

This code says to print FALSE when there is more than one answer returned (i.e. in cases when TRUE FALSE or FALSE TRUE).

Comment: `> k[[5]]-k[[4]]== c(1,1)
[1] TRUE TRUE`                     `> !length(unique(k[[5]]-k[[4]]==c(1,1)))==1
[1] FALSE` 
The answer I want on this line is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want the `all` function?

```
> k <- list(c(1L, 1L), c(3L, 3L))
> all(k[[2]]-k[[1]]== c(1,1))
[1] FALSE
> 
> k <- list(c(1L, 1L), c(2L, 3L))
> all(k[[2]]-k[[1]]== c(1,1))
[1] FALSE
> 
> k <- list(c(1L, 1L), c(2L, 2L))
> all(k[[2]]-k[[1]]== c(1,1))
[1] TRUE
```

Note that with @www solution

```
> k <- list(c(1L, 1L), c(3L, 3L))
> length(unique((k[[2]]-k[[1]]== c(1,1)))) == 1
[1] TRUE
```

Do you want `FALSE` and `FALSE` to evaluate to `TRUE`?